# Right to left programming in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, right-to-left

I am going to create **RTL** window using PyQt5 but can't do it. How do I create right to left window using PyQt5?

Answer (score 5):

Use the [layout direction property](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#layoutDirection-prop) of QWidget with setLayoutDirection and set it to `QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft`.

You can do so for the whole GUI application too using `setLayoutDirection` of the `QGuiApplication`.